# complex SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been coming up with a complex SQL statement for the description below.
So I have 3 tables as explained

**Clients**

1. client_id
2. name
3. email
4. booked [can be either 0 or 1]

**Accom**

1. accom_id
2. client_id
3. checkin [timestamp]
4. checkout [timestamp]

**Conf**

1. conf_id
2. client_id
3. checkin [timestamp
4. checkout

So The query is. I want to **select all records** for clients who are booked in **[client.booked = 1]** and their respective records in **Accom** or **conf** OR both between a **checkin and checkout timestamp** that is provided by the user.

This is what I have.

```
SELECT `client_id` FROM `accomm` WHERE `checkin` >= $fro AND `checkout` <= $to
SELECT `client_id` FROM `conf` WHERE `checkin` >= $fro AND `checkout` <= $to
```

Obviously this selects all the client_id's between the checkin and checkout provided, but do not filter the ID's who's booked value in **clients** is = 1

Comment: better questions display some sample data and desired output

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say this is too complex:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT c.* 
     FROM client c
LEFT JOIN accom a
       ON a.client_id = c.client_id
      AND a.checkin BETWEEN $from AND $to
LEFT JOIN conf co
       ON co.client_id = c.client_id
      AND co.checkin BETWEEN $from AND $to
    WHERE c.booked = 1
      AND a.client_id IS NOT NULL OR co.client_id IS NOT NULL
```

This assumes that you want just the client records and no duplicates.

Comment: Was about to answer with SQL that was almost identical...+1 for fast typing, lol.

Comment: Why use a LEFT JOIN with the IS NOT NULL checks in your WHERE, rather than use an INNER JOIN?

Comment: @mungea05 because I need to keep rows where 1 of accom or conf doesn't match the conditions.

Comment: @GDP Cheers for the edit! silly typo, probably have a crumb in my `.` key!

Comment: @arth, it's the little things that will make the OP crazy, lol

Comment: @arth I see. I read the OR as an AND in the final two WHERE statements.

Comment: @mungea05 Yep, I would use an INNER JOIN for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT c.* 
     FROM client c
    WHERE c.booked = 1
      AND ( 
            EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM accom a
                     WHERE a.client_id = c.client_id
                       AND a.checkin BETWEEN $from AND $to
                   )
            OR 
            EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM conf co
                     WHERE co.client_id = c.client_id
                       AND co.checkin BETWEEN $from AND $to
                   )
          )
```

For better performance, create these indexes:

- client (booked)
- conf (client_id, checkin)
- accom (client_id, checkin)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Client.client_id, name, email, facility_type, facility_id, checkin, checkout
  FROM Client INNER JOIN (
       SELECT 'Accom' AS facility_type, accom_id AS facility_id, client_id, checkin, checkout
         FROM Accom
       UNION
       SELECT 'Conf' AS facility_type, conf_id AS facility_id, client_id, checkin, checkout
         FROM Conf
       ) AS sub
    ON Client.client_id = sub.client_id
 WHERE booked = 1 AND checkin >= $from AND checkout <= $to;
```

Comment: You'll get dupes for some clients with this approach.

Comment: I read "and their respective records in Accom or conf OR both" as requesting the output to include the respective records. If they are in both, you would want both to be output. I can see how the question could be read either way.

Comment: Fair enough, I made an assumption there!